# How to speak of identity

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I am a French-Welsh bi-national living and working in France.
I am translating the institutional brochure of a French company whose activities are to print all types of 'identity' papers such as identity cards, passports, driving licenses etc. They also develop machines that control digital identity data, border control systems such as biometric passport control systems and sell their equipment worldwide.
Their new tagline in French is, 'Le droit d'être soi', which literally translated would be, 'The right to be oneself'.  Now, that doesn't sound very correct to me, unless of course I am mistaken. The other option that I'm still not happy with, would be, 'The right to be You'.
The meaning behind it is to say that whether you are a state or an individual you have the right to exercise all types of 'rights' pertaining to your the fact that you are a 'unique person' or state.
Any comments or suggestions would be most welcome.
Regards,
Rose-Noëlle
A quick feedback would be most welcome !

Comment: Both "the right to be oneself" and "the right to be you" suggest a more whimsical meaning; something like *the right to be the unique and special person you truly are.* Is that idea implied in the French?

Comment: "'The right to be oneself'. - what is "not very correct" about that?

Comment: It might be *slightly* more natural as *the right to be* ***yourself***, although *oneself* also sounds okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

Rose-Noelle,

Welcome to English Stackexchange.

The literal translation of 'The right to be oneself' is perfectly acceptable, easily understood and in this case is what should be used as you are performing translation services.